# Vaadin: restrict available RichTextArea format options

Tags: java, vaadin

I would like to only allow the following format options in a RichTextArea

- Regular
- Bold
- Italic
- Subscript / Superscript

I can't find any hints on how to do this. Except some information which is > 4 years old.

Any help on how to archive this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is still correct, there is no API for this requirement.
You need to make some changes to the RichTextArea styles. See [Vaadin RichTextArea Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-richtextarea.html).

If you look at the generated vaadin styles, you can find styles beginning with ".v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar". Based on the font-family "ThemeIcons" the PushButtons and ToggleButton are defined like this:

```
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Bold"] {
    content: "\f032";
}
```

To disable buttons, these settings need to be overridden with "display:none".
To avoid every single button to be handled like this, you can change the style for ToggleButton and PushButton:

```
.v-richtextarea .gwt-ToggleButton, .v-richtextarea .gwt-PushButton { ... }
```

**Requirements**:

- You just want to see the Toggle Buttons for Bold, Italic, Subscript and Superscript text, nothing else.
- For Regular re-formatting, I re-enabled the Push Button for "Remove Formatting".
- I suppose, you also want the buttons re-aligned to the left without any gaps.

**Solution** (working in modern browsers):

Change/Override the styles and recompile them for your application.

1.) Disable the bottom Toolbar (containing the dropdown boxes):

```
.gwt-RichTextToolbar-bottom { display: none; }
```

2.) Disable all PushButtons

```
.v-richtextarea .gwt-PushButton {
    display:none;
}
```

3.) Do not change the required Toggle Buttons for Bold, Italic, Subscript and Superscript; the original settings are:

```
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Bold"]:before {
    content: "\f032";
}
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Italic"]:before {
    content: "\f033";
}
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Subscript"]:before {
    content: "\f12c";
}
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Superscript"]:before {
    content: "\f12b";
}
```

4.) Disable specific ToggleButtons:

```
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Underline"] {
    display:none;
}
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Toggle Strikethrough"] {
    display:none;
}
```

5.) Re-enable the "Remove Formatting" PushButton by inheriting the former PushButton style removed for all other PushButtons in 2.)

```
.v-richtextarea .gwt-RichTextToolbar-top div[title="Remove Formatting"] {
    content: "\f12d";
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 37px;
    width: 37px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}
```

If you want to work with the built-in RichTextArea and change this stuff in detail you currently need to cope with the styles. Or you try another RichText/Wysiwyg component offered as [Vaadin Addons](https://vaadin.com/directory#!browse).

Comment: I hoped there would be an elegant solution by now. Thank you for your detailed and quick awnser. I will try the ckeditor addon then.